# Redundant Sorting for Aggregate Grouped-By Monotonic Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I'm developing a query against a table that contains a bunch of points in a time series.  The table can grow quite large, and so I want the query to effectively downsample the output by averaging points over fixed time intervals.  After writing the query, I'm surprised by how SQL Server (2008) has opted to execute the query.  The execution plan reveals an unnecessary sorting operation that would become expensive as the time series grows.  Here is the problem, reduced to a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Example]
(
    [x] FLOAT NOT NULL,
    [y] FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [x] ASC
    )
);

SELECT FLOOR([x]), AVG([y])
FROM [dbo].[Example]
GROUP BY FLOOR([x]);
```

Here I have (x,y) pairs that are already sorted by x (because of the clustered primary key), and I'm averaging y for each whole number x (by truncating with the `FLOOR` function).  I would expect that the table is already suitably sorted for the aggregate since `FLOOR` is a monotonic function.  Unfortunately, SQL Server decides that this data needs to be re-sorted, and here is the execution plan:

[image: Example Execution Plan]

Shouldn't SQL Server be able to perform a streaming aggregation over data grouped by a monotonic function of columns that are already suitably sorted?

Is there a general way to rewrite such queries so that SQL Server will see that the order is preserved?

**[Update]**
I've found an article on the subject [Things SQL needs: sargability of monotonic functions](http://explainextended.com/2010/02/19/things-sql-needs-sargability-of-monotonic-functions/) and, as the title suggests, it seems like this is an optimization that SQL Server doesn't yet do (in most cases).

Here are even simpler queries over `[dbo].[Example]` that demonstrate the point:

```
SELECT [x], [y]
FROM [dbo].[Example]
ORDER BY FLOOR([x]) --sort performed in execution plan

SELECT [x], [y]
FROM [dbo].[Example]
ORDER BY 2*[x] --NO sort performed in execution plan

SELECT [x], [y]
FROM [dbo].[Example]
ORDER BY 2*[x]+1 --sort performed in execution plan
```

In any single addition or multiplication, the query optimizer understands that the data already has the same order (and this is seen when you group by such expressions too). So it seems like the concept of monotonic functions is understood by the optimizer, just not generally applied.

I'm testing the computed column / index solution now, but it seems like this will dramatically increase the size of the persisted data since I will need several indices to cover the range of possible intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes:

- the plan that you see when table is empty and the plan when table has X rows can be absolutely different plans
- I don't think it is correct to have primary key on X field. Can there be two points that have the same X values?

I think you will have the best query performance if you do something like this:

```
create table Point
(
    PointId int identity(1, 1)
        constraint PK_Example_Id primary key,
    X float not null,
    Y float not null,
    FloorX as floor(x) persisted
)

create index IX_Point_FloorX_Y on Point(FloorX, Y)
```

Add some rows:

```
declare @RowCount int = 10000
while(@RowCount > 0)
begin
    insert Point
    values (cast(crypt_gen_random(2) as int), cast(crypt_gen_random(2) as int))
    set @RowCount -= 1
end
```

Query:

```
select floor(X), avg(Y)
from Point
group by floor(X)
```

or

```
select FloorX, avg(Y)
from Point
group by FloorX
```

both will have the same plan

Plan: no sorting

[image]

Another option - you can create indexed view. In this case you will have to query the view directly,  unless you have Enterprise Edition, which would use indexed view indexes even if you query table directly.

**[Edit]** Just realized I didn't explicitly answer your question. You asked why would SQL perform sort if `X` is clustered primary key. SQL does not perform sort on `X`, it performs sort on `floor(x)`. In other words, if `x` is already sorted, then `f(x)` would not necessarily have the same order, right?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Alex. In the data that I'm actually working with, the domain is time and the resolution of the standard `datetime` datatype is sufficient for uniqueness (a sampling rate faster than 3.33ms would never be allowed). Also, the function used to group results will not always be the same. In the example it's `floor`, but for the real time series data it could be every 30s, every 5min, every 10days, etc. I'm not sure it would be practical to persist and maintain computed columns and indices for each possible interval.

Comment: @Michael Petito - Reread your question and realized I did not explicitly answer your question. Updated the answer. Also, I don't think you can achieve good performance without adding index for the value you are grouping by.

Comment: To answer your edit, by definition, a monotonic (increasing) function like `floor` satisfies the condition that `if x <= y then f(x) <= f(y)` (order is preserved).  So yes, the purpose of my question is that, since x is already sorted, f(x) is already sorted, and so no sorting should be necessary for any aggregation grouped by f(x).

Comment: @Michael Petito: SQL Server almost always ignores indexes when there is any function on the columns of the index. Unless coded as an optimisation in the Query Optimiser, it doesn't do rigorous mathematical proofs.

Comment: @Michael - Just a note: if you switch x data type to decimal(n,m), the calculated column does not have to be persistent anymore. This is in case if you want to save space on this column.

Comment: I decided to go with this approach, using indices over non-persisted computed columns for the common intervals I need, and the original query for other (less common) intervals. Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server almost always ignores indexes when there is any function on the columns of the index. There are good reasons:

- The Query Optimiser (QO) uses statistics of data distribution.
  The function changes this: do you expect statistics to be generate *per query*?
- The function (in this case, definitely) can invalidate uniqueness of the index
  The QO can use uniqueness in it's plan generation

Some optimisations are coded in to QO (for example: COUNT vs EXISTS in an IF) but it doesn't do rigorous mathematical proofs: they don't apply to query response times

There is an [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/653206/the-optimizer-should-be-able-to-understand-the-invertability-of-built-in-intrinsics-on-dates-for-the-purposes-of-index-sargability) for some datetime functions too (which I actually disagree with because there are too many permutations of functions to optimise out: so we'd have inconsistency)

Otherwise, the indexed computed column solution from Alex Aza is what I'd do

Edit:

Read your link in updated question.

FLOOR changes strictly monotonic to monotonic. That is, x is unique so is strictly monotonic. FLOOR(x) is monotonic.

If you have any WHERE clauses statistics becomes important: as you said you posted simplified examples.

And for the x*2 + 1 example you posted: at what point do you think should SQL Server *stop* evaluating expressions? It's a cost based optimiser of course..

I think it's fair that SQL Server behaves this way: day to day my EXISTS optimisation example is far more useful.

Comment: I wouldn't expect statistics to be generated per query, but at the same time I don't understand why statistics would be important to determining whether or not the data is suitably sorted.  Yes, the function invalidates uniqueness, but not order, and I don't see this requiring much effort to prove (see the article in my update). This definitely does impact query response times; sorting is a relatively expensive operation!

Comment: +1 Your MS Connect link is effectively what I'm trying to do too.  Too bad the Microsoft response doesn't link to an examination of the "numerous workarounds".

Comment: Yes gbn, I did read the entire article before posting it. "For an expression to maintain the B-Tree order, it is necessary and sufficient for this expression to be a monotonic function of the argument being indexed." There is no requirement that the function be strictly monotonic; lack of strictness will just slightly change how you navigate the index.

Comment: The only `WHERE` clause I need beyond the example is to restrict the range of the domain (x in the example) without transformation, so the original statistics would still apply. I can't comment on the cost of the optimization, but it seems like at least 47 people on MS Connect would disagree with you on the subject of its utility.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question. In cases like this we want to have another table and use CROSS APPLY, like the following example that uses table Numbers that stores all the numbers between Min(X)/YourStepInMinutes AND Max(x)/YourStepInMinutes, and two more numbers around Min and Max. This query runs as nested loops, does not need a sort:

```
SELECT n.n, Avg(p.y)
FROM dbo.Numbers AS n
CROSS APPLY (SELECT p.y 
  FROM dbo.Points AS p 
  WHERE p.x<n*YourStepInMinutes AND (n-1)*YourStepInMinutes<=p.x
) As p
```

Edit: While this solution does need a join which is not free, i would not make a blanket statement that is is always slow. Sorting a lot of data may all of a sudden become very slow - you are sorting 10% rows more, and your sort may be 10 times slower. On the other hand, this approach scales better, because it does not require one big huge sort.

Also because we don't need a persisted computed column, we can immediately use this query for intervals of any size, like 17 minutes.

Comment: This is an interesting approach -- it probably is slower than Alex Aza's solution because of the join, but could require less storage space since the computed intervals can be re-used.